# Creat remote connection to mysql with mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have a new server with MySQL installed, 1 user (an other than root user), I setup a database with tables.
I want to be able to connect from my other server with my PHP code to this new server's database.
So for that, I make a

```
mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $db_port);
```

but there is this error :

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002)
```

I can affirme that this is not a PHP code error, but certainly a SQL one.
I don't know if that come from remote possibility connexion with my new server, or a problem of user generation.
Just to begin, we do agree that in PHP `$servername` is egal to my new server's IP and `$db_port` is egal to 3306, like return by `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` in mysql ?

And thank you very much for your time,
I ask my question here, because I did a lot of research on the subject and nothing helped me.
Can someone enlighten me ?

Comment: this tells you that your mariadb is **not** running, check the error log for further information.

Comment: I don't use mariadb, I'm just using mysql, so I restart mysql, and there is no change

Comment: There s not enough information, what is your host name, can you connect with mysql clientg or workbench with thuis credentilas. the error sweems also a bit short, there should be further information. Check your myslq error log, i think there should be an error. so please consider all what i wrozte add it to your question,and espeicially the error log, whic i  mentioned twice, is very important.

Comment: Ok I do all of that and I come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who had the same problem, I finally solved it :
I create a db 
`CREATE MYSQL db_name;`
after I create a user
`CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`
`%` mean from everywhere.
After that I used
`GRANT your_privileges ON db_name.* TO 'user_name'@'%';`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

After that, I just had to open my firewall provider to the MYSQL port (3306), and I opened it to every incoming ip.
And that was good !

Thank you for your help :)